# How to send @RequestParam in AJAX POST request

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, api, spring-restcontroller

I have my API which accepts Request Param:

```
    @PostMapping(value = "/export")
    @ResponseBody   
    public ResponseEntity<String> bulkExport(
        @RequestParam(value = "managedObjects", required = false) List<String> managedObjects) {
        //data
        }
   );
```

I want to send AJAX POST request.

```
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      //url: "policy/js_policy",
      url: "/export/ ,
      async: false,
      data: { "managedObjects": ["Audit","Logs"]},
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataType: "json",
      complete: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus) {
        //File Handling
      }
    });
```

I tried to send managedObjects in URL. In data also I am sending the same.But my API is not working. How to send the @RequestParam from AJAX POST request exactly?

Answer (score 3):

pass a list in `Query Param`

```
$.ajax({
      ...
      url: "/export?managedObjects=Audit,Logs" ,
      ...
    });
```

pass a list in `Request Body`

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "/export/",
  ...
  data: {managedObjects[0]: "Audit",
         managedObjects[1]: "Logs"}
  ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try stringifying your data:

```
var data = {
   managedObjects: ["Audit", "Logs"]
}
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "/export/",
  async: false,
  data: JSON.Stringify(data),
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
  complete: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus) {
    
  }
});
```

Additionally you should use "name" instead "value" in @RequestParam:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/export")
@ResponseBody   
public ResponseEntity<String> bulkExport(
    @RequestParam(name = "managedObjects", required = false) List<String> managedObjects) {
    //data
    }
```

);

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to modify something in AJAX rather than API, as the API code is already fixed.

Comment: Oh actually noticed that value is just as fine.

Comment: Throwing off another idea for your ajax call, edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is just with list that you want to send in your request.

```
var dataToSend = {
          list: [{ fieldname: 'ABC' }, { fieldname: 'DEF' }]; // your list should something like this.
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      //url: "policy/js_policy",
      url: "/export/?managedObjects=" + Mos ,
      async: false,
      data: JSON.stringify(dataToSend),
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataType: "json",
      complete: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus) {
        
      }
    });
```